# How to avoid for loops and use an alternative method in this code ( python and postgres sql)?. Below is my code

Tags: python, postgresql, for-loop

##Here is my code.I want to get rid of the for loops here. Can you please suggest an alterantive methods in python which can be used for the same logic##

```
usa_records = cursor.fetchall()
    for k in csv_files:#reading csv files
      with open(k, 'r') as f:
          reader = csv.reader(f)
          next(reader)  # Skip the header row.
          for row in reader:
              status = 0
              for m in usa_records:
                  if (m[6] == row[6]):
                      status = status + 1

                      row[0] = m[0] if m[0] is not None else row[0]
                      row[1] = m[1] if m[1] is not None else row[1]
                      row[2] = m[2] if m[2] is not None else row[2]
                      row[3] = m[3] if m[3] is not None else

                      row[17] = m[17] if m[17] is not None else row[17]

                      sql_update_query = """Update usa set technology=%s,   company_name=%s,contact_name=%s,first_name=%s,last_name=%s,title=%s,email=%s,person_linkedin_url=%s,web_address=%s,company_linkedin_url=%s,company_address=%s,city=%s,state=%s,company_phone=%s,employees=%s,industry=%s,country=%s where id = %s"""
                      cursor.execute(sql_update_query,
                                     (row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8],
                                      row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16],
                                      row[17]))
                      conn.commit()

                      row_count = cursor.rowcount
                      print(row_count, "Records Updated")
                      break
                  else:
                      pass
              if status == 0:
                  cursor.execute(
                      "INSERT INTO usa VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s,%s,%s)",
                      row)

                  conn.commit()
                  print("created new data")
```

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to use clean code principles and divide your logic into smaller functions. This will reduce nesting and make your code more readable.

Here's some pseudocode:

```py
usa_records = cursor.fetchall()
process_csv_files(csv_files, usa_records)


def process_csv_files(csv_files, usa_records):
    for k in csv_files:  #reading csv files
        with open(k, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            next(reader)  # Skip the header row.

            process_csv_content(reader, usa_records)

def process_csv_content(reader):
    for row in reader:
        usa_record = find_usa_record_by_id(row[6], usa_records)

        if not usa_record:
            # INSERT in the database
        else:
            # UPDATE the database

def find_usa_record_by_id(id, usa_records):
    # Implement a function that returns the record based on the given id.
    pass
```

Comment: I tried this code but its not working correctly. Its neither updating or adding data from csv files.Can you write a full code assuming you have some csv files in a folder and you are going to upload those data into your postgres sql table. ( Assume that same headers exist in both csv and database table).

Comment: @MaheshKrishnan, can you share the code you tried? As I mentioned, I shared a pseudocode of a potential way you could structure your code, it might need some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

What's the reason you want to remove the for loops? I mean, what's the goal? By knowing the reasons, we can propose different approaches.

Is it about "code readability"? Is it because of performance? Is it just an exercise?

Comment: For both. Performance and code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Pandas. It looks like most of what you're doing could be completed with somewhat simple dataframe operations. For example, reading a csv:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

And rather than looping over rows, you can use `.apply`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html